# How to use View.OnTouchListener instead of onClick

Tags: android, android-layout, user-input

I'm developing an Android 2.2.2 application for a client and he wants to do the following:

Now I have a button with an onClick event but he doesn't like, he wants to dectect when user release the button.

I've found [View.OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) which I think this is what I need to use but, is there any posibility to add this event to xml like I did with onClick?

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnSaveNewGate"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/btnSaveNewGate_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/btnSaveNewGate_height"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGrGateType"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/btnSaveNewGate_marginTop"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/layout_empty"
    android:onClick="onSaveNewGateClick"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/save_gate_selector" />
```

I have two questions more:

Which is the event associated when user releases his finger?

Is there any guidelines which prohibit using `View.OnTouchListener` instead of `onClick`?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The event when user releases his finger is `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`. I'm not aware if there are any guidelines which prohibit using View.OnTouchListener instead of onClick(), most probably it depends of situation.

Here's a sample code:

```
imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

            // Do what you want
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use a switch on event.getAction() and the cases would be MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and so forth.

Comment: on one plus one it shows MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN instead of click

Comment: Note that if you return false there, the if clause will never fire. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20359888/564628

Answer (score 19):

Presumably, if one wants to use an `OnTouchListener` rather than an `OnClickListener`, then the extra functionality of the `OnTouchListener` is needed. This is a supplemental answer to show more detail of how an `OnTouchListener` can be used.

**Define the listener**

Put this somewhere in your activity or fragment.

```
private View.OnTouchListener handleTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.i("TAG", "touched down");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.i("TAG", "moving: (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.i("TAG", "touched up");
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

**Set the listener**

Set the listener in `onCreate` (for an Activity) or `onCreateView` (for a Fragment).

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(handleTouch);
```

**Notes**

- `getX` and `getY` give you the coordinates relative to the view (that is, the top left corner of the view). They will be negative when moving above or to the left of your view. Use `getRawX` and `getRawY` if you want the absolute screen coordinates.
- You can use the `x` and `y` values to determine things like swipe direction.

Answer (score 6):

OnClick is triggered when the user releases the button.  But if you still want to use the TouchListener you need to add it in code.  It's just:

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    // Implementation;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for use sample touch listener just you need this code

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
    view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, null, 0);

    return true;
}
```