# Android - How to trigger RecyclerView OnItemTouchListener on entire screen

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment, ontouchlistener

I have a RecyclerView with children. When I touch a child, shows a `DialogFragment`, and when I release, the `DialogFragment` is dismissed. But `onTouch` is only trigger inside of child area. I want to make the `onTouch` `ACTION_UP` trigger the entire screen.

`RecyclerView` custom `OnItemTouchListener`:

```
galleryRecycler.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new ClosetGalleryAdapter.RecyclerTouchListener(
                    getContext().getApplicationContext(),
                    galleryRecycler,
                    new ClosetGalleryAdapter.ClickListener() {

                        ClosetFragDialog dialogFragment;
                        FragmentManager fm;

                        boolean is_pressed = false;
                        boolean isLongCLick = false;
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                         Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                if (is_pressed) {
                                    dialogFragment.show(fm, "info_frag");
                                    isLongCLick = true;
                                }
                            }
                        };

                        @Override
                        public void onTouch(View view, int position, MotionEvent e) {

                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putSerializable("look", looks.get(position));

                            fm = getFragmentManager();
                            dialogFragment = new ClosetFragDialog();
                            dialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                            if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                is_pressed = true;
                                // 500ms - to determine that this is a long press
                                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 300);
                            } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && is_pressed && isLongCLick) {
                                DialogFragment frag = (DialogFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("info_frag");
                                frag.dismiss();
                                is_pressed = false;
                                isLongCLick = false;
                            } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && is_pressed) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                is_pressed = false;
                                isLongCLick = false;
                            } else {

                            }

                        }
                    }));
```

Custom `OnItemTouchListener`:

```
public static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private ClosetGalleryAdapter.ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {

        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if(child != null && clickListener != null) {
            clickListener.onTouch(child, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child), e);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface ClickListener {
    void onTouch(View view, int position, MotionEvent e);
}
```

Comment: Please add your codes

Comment: @Ivan Barayev Added..

Comment: `OnItemTouchListener` is designed to be used on the children of the Recyclerview. It isn't meant to be used on the whole view. Consider using something like view's `OnTouchListener`

Comment: Still the same.. When move the finger out of the child area, trigger `ACTION_UP`. I want that it only trigger when user release the touch in any point of screen.

Comment: Did you implement it similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690504/how-to-use-view-ontouchlistener-instead-of-onclick