# buttons held down

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, onlongclicklistener

Morning

Any help appreciated.
Morning

Any help appreciated.Morning

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is neither tutorial site, free workforce nor web search replacement. We can help you on [some topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to [put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) on the subject in the first place, including elementary [(re)search](https://google.com/). If you think you did that, read [how to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: i have added my tried code im not asking for a tutorial just some help where im going wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is it not working for you? Can you show the logs your app is producing? This will provide us with more information to help debug your issue.

You could also have a look here [for more tutorials on how to implement OnTouchListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690504/how-to-use-view-ontouchlistener-instead-of-onclick)

Comment: It only ever adds 1 or takes 1 even when i hold it down, it never repeats the action

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284224/android-hold-button-to-repeat-action